# Getting eclipse to highlight and validate HTML files

Tags: html, eclipse

How can I configure Eclipse to properly syntax highlight and validate HTML files?

At the moment, Eclipse simply offers spelling suggestions for tags and attributes - an exact opposite of desired behavior.

Comment: Which editor are you opening the files with? Which flavor of Eclipse (one with WTP)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is likely that you do not have an HTML editor plugin in Eclipse.

You can download the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) plugin which has a decent HTML editor.

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be a difficult thing to figure out. I already had an HTML editor installed as part of Eclipse, but it wasn't getting loaded.

Go to Preferences > General > Editors > File Association and click on *.html (and do the same for *.htm). If you have an HTML editor installed, you should see it in the list. Just click it and then click Default to make Eclipse open HTML files using the HTML editor.

If you don't have an HTML editor installed, WTP is fine, per Rahul's suggestion. You may then need to do the above steps to make sure the HTML Editor is chosen when you edit an HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Colorer plugin for Eclipse](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Web Tools Platform already installed, enable validation of HTML files within Eclipse Preferences and make sure you are using the proper eclipse editor.